# XML issue with array indexing

Tags: c#, xml, arrays

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<servers>  
  <server serverid="server1" asset="Sample" >
    <port portid ="port1" asset="Sample"  ></port>  
    <port portid ="port2" asset="Sample"  ></port>      
  </server>

  <server serverid="server2" asset="Sample" >
    <port portid ="port1" asset="Sample"  ></port> 
    <port portid ="port2" asset="Sample"  ></port>    
    <port portid ="port3" asset="Sample"  ></port>
    <port portid ="port4" asset="Sample"  ></port>        
  </server>
<server serverid="server1" asset="Sample" >
    <port portid ="port1" asset="Sample"  ></port> 
    <port portid ="port2" asset="Sample"  ></port>    
    <port portid ="port3" asset="Sample"  ></port>   
  </server>

</servers>
```

I am trying to add Server XElements and port XElements to the existing XML DOC.I tried the following code,

```
int[] test = new int[3];
string[] PortName1 = new string[3];
string[] PortId1 = new string[3];
PortName1[0]="portname1";
PortName1[1] = "portname2";
PortName1[2] = "portname3";

PortId1[0] = "port1";
PortId1[1] = "port2";
PortId1[2] = "port3";
var fileName = @"C:\sample.xml";
var xdoc = XDocument.Load(fileName);

var server = 
    new XElement("server",
        new XAttribute("serverid", ServerId),
        new XAttribute("name", ServerName),
            test.Select(sample =>
                new XElement("port",
                    new XAttribute("asset", PortName),
                    new XAttribute("portid", PortId)
                ))
        );
```

Everything is working fine,but the problem is PortName & PortId are string array variables.Dont know how to get indexed dynamic values for each iterate of "test".For me everytime it is getting the zero index values only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do you need test array? You should use PortName1 array or PortId1, like this:

```
var portIdIndex = 0; // declare variable somewhere before

PortName1.Select(port =>
             new XElement("port",
                 new XAttribute("asset", port),
                 new XAttribute("portid", PortId1[portIdIndex++])
             ))
```

Or like this:

```
PortName1.Select(port =>
             new XElement("port",
                 new XAttribute("asset", port),
                 new XAttribute("portid", PortId1[PortName1.IndexOf(port)])
             ))
```

Or you can combine PortId and PortName using anonymous types:

```
var portData = new [] { 
    new { PortName="Port 1", PortId = 1}, 
    new { PortName="Port 2", PortId = 2} 
};

portData.Select(port =>
     new XElement("port",
         new XAttribute("asset", port.PortName),
         new XAttribute("portid", port.PortId)
     ))
```

Get data from user input:

```
var portData = new List<string[]>();
// here we need to get data like this:
var portName = Console.ReadLine();
var portId = Console.ReadLine();
portData.Add(new string[]{portName, portId});

portData.Select(port =>
     new XElement("port",
         new XAttribute("asset", port[0]),
         new XAttribute("portid", port[1])
     ))
```

A little [demo](http://dotnetfiddle.net/xdQITq).

Comment: :PortName & PortId's are dynamic,sometimes 2(size) & sometimes 3,it depends on userinput.so can u suggest,under portdata how to generate dynamic portname's & portId's

Comment: am getting error @Tuple (i guess tuple is a class that needs to define)

Comment: It is well known type of .Net http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/dd268536(v=vs.110).aspx, which version of .net do you use?

Comment: It should be available. Hm, ok, let's use array, see my updated answer.

Comment: @user1676709: The version of Visual Studio you're using isn't actually relevant - which version of .NET are you targeting in your project? That will determine which types are available.

Comment: actually am getting error @ portName, portId (Cannot implicitly convert type 'string[]' to string).@ Console.ReadLine(); passing an array.

Comment: @user1676709 Really? That's odd, please see my demo how it should work: http://dotnetfiddle.net/xdQITq

Comment: @Tony really your demo helped me a lot.And thanks a lot for your help & patience till the issue get resolved.Thanks a lot again.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using .NET 4, you can just use [`Zip`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267698%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
var server = 
    new XElement("server",
        new XAttribute("serverid", ServerId),
        new XAttribute("name", ServerName),
            PortName1.Zip(PortId1, (name, id) =>
                new XElement("port",
                    new XAttribute("asset", name),
                    new XAttribute("portid", id)
                ))
        );
```

If you're not using .NET 4 or later, you can implement `Zip` very easily in your own code - Eric Lippert has [sample code in a blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/05/07/zip-me-up.aspx).

(As a side note, I'd encourage you to follow .NET naming conventions - I'd change the names of `PortId1` and `PortName1` to `portIds` and `portNames` for example.)